# Ruby Rack & Multiple Internet Domains

Tags: ruby, rack, middleware, multiple-domains

I am having two domains running each a separate web application that should be served by one server i.e. one ip address. Depending on the request the proper application should be selected by some rack middleware. Is there already one out or do I have to write my own? (Writing my own wouldn't be a problem but if I could use an existing one it would be perfect. ;-)

Thanks for your support.

Comment: what is the condition to request the proper application? only the domain name?

Comment: Precisely. E.g. http://www.one.com -> web application #1; http://www.two.com -> web application #2. The domain name is part of the request and can be used to route the request to the appropriate application. It's pretty easy. I googled around but couldn't find anything.

Comment: does it have to be selected by the rack middleware? apache can't be used?

Comment: Yes, has to be done in rack. No cheating allowed. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Similar answer to this question: [use some Middleware only for specific Rack website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598264/use-some-middleware-only-for-specific-rack-website)

URLMap will probably do the job.

- Examples: http://blog.ninjahideout.com/posts/rack-urlmap-and-kicking-ass
- Official docs: http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/classes/Rack/URLMap.html

Comment: The ninjahideout link is down, and missing from archive.org due to robots.txt.  How sad.